# How can I create a gadient background in Qt3D?

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, qt3d

I am looking for the C++ code that creates a gradient background (e.g. from black to white). Currently I only have a solid color by setting the clear color of Qt3DWindow:

```
Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow->defaultFrameGraph()->setClearColor(QColor(QRgb(0x4d4d9f)))
```

How can I make a gradient?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but did you have a look at the [Wave example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qt3d-wave-example.html)? They achieve this effect with a shader there.